# Run gnuplot scripts in background within a shell script

Tags: shell, gnuplot

I can't run my gnuplot script in background within a shell script. Something like in following example

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 1 2 3
do 
run gnu_script($i).p
done
```

As per the answer given by Christoph I could able to do it. But still the figure windows are coming and not letting me to do anything in the computer.

Comment: If you want to run them sequentially (one after the other) in the background, just put an ampersand (`&`) after `done`. If you want to run them all in parallel in the background, put the ampersand after the `gnuplot` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something simple as

```
for i in 1 2 3
do 
    gnuplot script$i.gp &
done
```

That assumes, that you have different scripts `script1.gp`, `script2.gp` and `script3.gp`.

If you have only a single script and want to pass the iteration number to it, you could do it with

```
for i in 1 2 3
do
    gnuplot -e "i=${i}" script.gp &
done
```

A simple gnuplot script `script.gp` for testing this is

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output sprintf('script%d.png', i)
plot x title sprintf('%d', i)
pause 10
```

The `pause 10` makes gnuplot pause for 10 seconds.

Comment: @ Christoph . As per your answer I could able to do it. But still the figure windows are coming up and not letting me to do anything in the computer.  Would you please help me if there is any additional commands. Thank you!!